# How to search for a modification of an element in a web page using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am a beginner with Cucumber/Selenium, and I have a web page on which there is a table on which one of the boxes can be 0 or 1. my problem is that the value of this box varies over time, I have tried many times to check that this element is 1 then 0 after a certain time, but I do not succeed in it.

I know how to get the css or xpath of this element, but it doesn't change when the value of this element changes, and no way to get the associated value (0 or 1) of this element.

What I've tried:

By inspecting the part of the source code associated with this element I saw that a character in the source code went from 1 to 0 at the same time as the box, and I tried to check this change with driver.getPageSource.contains ("the area around the source code that contains the changed character*"), after waiting a little with a wait instruction to allow the source code the time to change, but this has never worked.

Anyone have an idea to help me do it right? It is very important for me to find the solution to my problem,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the text from an element, use:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.XPath(*your XPath here*)).getText();
```

This will output the inner text from the element at the moment you call it. If your element doesn't have any inner text, use:

```
getAttribute("value")
```

When trying to get the value of an element, it is best practice that you specify what your element is and then try to get the value from it, rather than getting the entire page source and making sure what you expect is contained in it.

There are many resources that will help you gain an understanding of how Selenium and Cucumber work, which I would recommend having a look through before trying to build a solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked ! As I am a beginer, this idea of a value of an element was unclear for me, but now it is better, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend next time to show what kind of code you have tried up until your issue. This will help the people trying to help you and make it easier for us to point you in the right direction. If you could set this as the answer, then people can see the post has been closed